# Get specific value from json field based on last created_at date

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am using retool, which uses AlaSQL to query JSON, trying to get the value from a field that has multiple items; I only want to return the value of the field stock for the key with the latest created_at date.

[image: screenshot]

```
select tracked_products 
from {{ean.data}} 
where created_at=(select MAX(created_at) from {{ean.data}});
```

I can actually get to the fields I want to like this but I do not understand how to filter further

```
select tracked_products 
from {{ean.data}} 
where price < 40
```

result from above query in plain text

```
[
  {
    "id": 172165913,
    "offer_data_id": 2208536,
    "stock": 2,
    "sold": 0,
    "revenue": "0.00",
    "price": 39.99,
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-12-16T12:12:26.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-16T12:12:26.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 173409443,
    "offer_data_id": 2208536,
    "stock": 2,
    "sold": 0,
    "revenue": "0.00",
    "price": 34.99,
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-12-17T03:15:58.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-17T03:15:58.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 174659591,
    "offer_data_id": 2208536,
    "stock": 2,
    "sold": 0,
    "revenue": "0.00",
    "price": 34.99,
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-12-18T16:22:45.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-18T16:22:45.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 175895075,
    "offer_data_id": 2208536,
    "stock": 2,
    "sold": 0,
    "revenue": "0.00",
    "price": 34.99,
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-12-19T03:18:53.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-19T03:18:53.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 177134025,
    "offer_data_id": 2208536,
    "stock": 2,
    "sold": 0,
    "revenue": "0.00",
    "price": 34.99,
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-12-20T15:35:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-20T15:35:48.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 178391290,
    "offer_data_id": 2208536,
    "stock": 2,
    "sold": 0,
    "revenue": "0.00",
    "price": 34.99,
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-12-21T03:09:22.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-21T03:09:22.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 179654380,
    "offer_data_id": 2208536,
    "stock": 1,
    "sold": 1,
    "revenue": "34.99",
    "price": 34.99,
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-12-22T03:13:50.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-22T03:13:50.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 180918092,
    "offer_data_id": 2208536,
    "stock": 1,
    "sold": 0,
    "revenue": "0.00",
    "price": 34.99,
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-12-23T03:19:42.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-23T03:19:42.000000Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       (array_agg(j->>'stock') OVER (PARTITION BY tracked_products ORDER BY j->>'created_at' DESC)[1] AS stock
FROM ean.data
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(tracked_products :: jsonb, '$[*]') AS j
WHERE price < 40
```

This query relies on a text sorting on `created_at` which should be compliant with the actual date format of this text field.

`jsonb_path_query` is used instead of `json_array_elements` so that to avoid an error when tracked_products is not a json of type array.

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WPPsFAAl)

Refer to the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) for more info about json manipulation

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I tried it but does not work

message:"Parse error on line 2:
...ked_products -> 0 ->> 'stock' from  ? 
-----------------------^
Expecting 'LITERAL', 'BRALITERAL', 'LPAR', 'NUMBER', 'IF', 'REPLACE', 'DATEADD', 'DATEDIFF', 'INTERVAL', got 'GT'"

Comment: I will update my proposal but it would be much more easier if you can share in plain text the result of the query `select tracked_products from {{ean.data}} where price < 40`

Comment: I updated my initial post with the data, thanks again